# Adding blank row based on cell value/checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to this community and not very familiar with Macros and I am desperately seeking for someone's help!!

I am currently working on a google sheet and would like to create a macro that automatically adds a new blank row below my existing row every time a value in a  given column is equal to `TRUE`.

Every help will be really much appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet? Is  there data already in the row? It's helpful to see what your trying to do so that we can direct to the most intelligent choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might mean something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var inclShts=['Sheet127'];
  if(inclShts.indexOf(sh.getName())==-1){return; }
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet127' && e.range.columnStart==13) {
    sh.insertRowAfter(e.range.rowStart);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).insertCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

If you start with something like this:

[image]

And click on the unchecked box then you end up with something like this:

[image]

If that's not what meant then please go to the same amount of effort to explain your question as I did to explain my guess at the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really useful! It is exactly what I was trying to do!! Sorry for not having been more clear in expressing my problem.

Really appreciated!

Enjoy

Comment: If that answered your question, I’d appreciate it if you’ll check it off. Thanks.